# Dialog Box to get user text input on SurfaceView

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-alertdialog, surfaceview

I am wondering how I can get user input at the end of a game I am programming. Basically, when you lose three lives, I want to stop the game (stop all threads) and then display some sort of dialog box that allows the user to give their name so it can be saved with the high score. This is all being done in a SurfaceView, however. Does anybody have any good references to something like this? Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can simply use [FrameLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html) and put your SurfaceView there along with other layout which has your text entry forms plus any labels for it...

FrameLayout is capable of stacking several views on top of eachother so that would do what you need I guess.

Comment: So could I use an event that occurs in my SurfaceView to trigger something in the FrameLayout to display the Dialog??

Comment: I guess you can just make your text entry view visible when time comes. That is you will need to hide it initially. See documentation for View.setVisibility(int) method in sdk.